# Can't Mount USB drive FreeBSD

Tags: usb, mount, freebsd, qemu

I've been trying to mount a USB drive to my FreeBSD install for an unreasonable amount of time now to no avail.

[image]

At this point, I have looked at countless forum posts and manual pages and I am not quite sure of what I'm doing wrong.

glabel list output:

[glabel list output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6b5Y.png)

Comment: What is the output of `glabel list`?

Comment: I'll append the glabel output to the original post as an image

Comment: Did you follow [the Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/disks/#usb-disks)?